# Exclude zero when sampling random integers

Tags: list-manipulation, random

I want to generate triplets of random integers over where the integers are in the range -9 to 9 (inclusive) but excluding zero. How can I do that?

I have the following table.

```
Table[a -> RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 3], {50}] // Column
```

> ```
> {a -> {0, 9, 6}},
> {a -> {7, -3, 1}},
> {a -> {-8, -2, -6}},
> {a -> {9, 0, 2}},
> {a -> {-2, 5, 6}},
> {a -> {0, 4, -2}},
> {a -> {8, -5, -1}},
> {a -> {3, -4, -9}},
> {a -> {-8, 7, 6}},
> {a -> {-9, 8, 5}},
> {a -> {2, -1, 9}},
> {a -> {7, 0, 2}},
> {a -> {5, -2, 0}},
> {a -> {1, -9, -6}},
> {a -> {0, -8, 0}},
> {a -> {-9, -9, -2}},
> {a -> {9, -2, -3}},
> {a -> {6, -1, -5}},
> {a -> {-3, 2, 1}},
> {a -> {-7, 3, 0}},
> {a -> {8, 4, -5}},
> {a -> {-9, -1, 0}},
> {a -> {1, 0, -4}},
> {a -> {0, -4, 3}},
> {a -> {-1, -9, -6}},
> {a -> {9, 8, -3}},
> {a -> {6, -2, 4}},
> {a -> {2, 3, 8}},
> {a -> {-9, 1, -4}},
> {a -> {8, -1, -9}},
> {a -> {-7, 7, 9}},
> {a -> {-8, -7, 2}},
> {a -> {2, 3, -7}},
> {a -> {-2, 9, 5}},
> {a -> {9, 1, 0}},
> {a -> {8, 0, -6}},
> {a -> {-4, -8, 1}},
> {a -> {8, -5, 6}},
> {a -> {-9, -4, -9}},
> {a -> {9, 7, -8}},
> {a -> {9, 8, -5}},
> {a -> {9, 5, 5}},
> {a -> {-4, -5, -4}},
> {a -> {-3, 2, 0}},
> {a -> {-9, -9, 0}},
> {a -> {-7, 1, -4}},
> {a -> {7, 6, -5}},
> {a -> {-4, 1, -6}},
> {a -> {-5, -9, 0}},
> {a -> {-6, 2, -6}}
> ```

I don't want the zeros that appear above. I have used DeleteCases`and Replace` with no results,

Comment: How about `Table[a -> Table[(-1)^RandomInteger[{1, 2}] RandomInteger[{1,  9}], {3}], {50}] // Column`

Comment: @jose check the solution i posted below if you are interested in using `DeleteCases` and `Replace`

Comment: How to remove repeated elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Table[a -> RandomChoice[Join[-Range[9], Range[9]], 3], 50] // Column
```

Comment: `RandomSample` takes 3 *distinct* choices.  It should be `RandomChoice`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm left with this solution v / s the random

Comment: How to remove repeated elements

Comment: you mean DeleteDuplicates@    ?

Comment: I tried with DeleteDuplicates but the list is reduced to 3 to 2 elements
I need it to be 3 elements

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 3]
```

with

```
RandomChoice[Delete[Range[-9, 9], 10], 3]
```

#### Update

The OP asks in a comment below that the selected triples be constrained so that no element triples is duplicated. I would enforce that constraint with a recursive helper command.

```
With[{items = Delete[Range[-9, 9], 10]},
  helper :=
    Module[{triple},
      triple = DeleteDuplicates @ RandomSample[items, 3];
      If[Length[triple] == 3, triple, helper]]]

SeedRandom[42]; Column[rules = Table[a -> helper, 50]]
```

> ```
> a -> {2, 9, -9}
> a -> {5, -3, -6}
> a -> {9, 7, 8}
> ...
> a -> {4, -2, -6}
> a -> {-1, -7, 9}
> a -> {-7, 9, -5}
> ```

The following proves the above result contains no triple with duplicate elements.

```
AllTrue[rules, Length[Union[#[[2]]]] === 3 &]
```

> `True`

Comment: `RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 3] RandomInteger[9, 3]` should work, too.

Comment: @J.M. That should be `RandomInteger[{1,9}, 3]` (I also thought it starts at 1, but it turns out it starts at 0.)

Comment: How to remove repeated elements

Comment: Instead of `Delete` referring to a position, I'd probably use either `Cases[Range[-9, 9], Except[0]]` or `DeleteCases[Range[-9, 9], 0]`.

Comment: @kirma. Seems obvious to me that in a sequence ranging from `-n` to `n`, the zero term is always the `n + 1`-th  element. Why not use that fact?

Comment: @m_goldberg Well... my personal view is that it's mostly pedagogically questionable, although correct. `Cases`/`DeleteCases` work with more complex inputs without head-scratching, and are hardly any more complicated to express.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in distinct triples, you might want to generate the entire list of possibilities and then use [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample):

```
samples = RandomSample[Tuples[DeleteCases[Range[-9,9],0], 3], 50];
Thread[a -> samples] //Short
```

> {a->{-1,3,5},a->{5,-9,-7},a->{8,6,-6},<<44>>,a->{-9,-8,-1},a->{2,-1,9},a->{8,-9,-6}}

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all entries with zeros:

```
t = Table[a -> RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 3], {50}];
DeleteCases[t, HoldPattern[a -> p : {__}] /; MemberQ[p, 0]]
```

also this will replace entries where zeros are present:

```
replacements = Range[-9, -1]~Join~Range[1, 9];
Replace[t, HoldPattern[a -> {OrderlessPatternSequence[(p : 0 ..), (t : Except[0] ..)]}] :> 
a -> {t}~Join~RandomChoice[replacements, Length@{p}], {1}]
```

Demo:

```
t // Short
(* {a -> {8, -2, -1}, a -> {8, 6, 0}, a -> {9, 5, -4}, a -> {9, 0, 0}, 
a -> {-7, 0, 4}, a -> {8, -5, -6}, a -> {4, 7, 2}, a -> {0, 3, 2}, <<35>>,
a -> {-5, -1, -6}, a -> {5, 7, -5}, a -> {-2, -3, 3}, a -> {-4, 0, 4},
a -> {1, 7, 3}, a -> {0, 9, -1}, a -> {-7, -4, -4}} *)

DeleteCases[t, HoldPattern[a -> p : {__}] /; MemberQ[p, 0]]//Short
(* {a -> {8, -2, -1}, a -> {9, 5, -4}, a -> {8, -5, -6}, a -> {4, 7, 2}, 
a -> {8, 5, -7}, a -> {5, 2, 3}, a -> {-5, 9, -5}, a -> {1, 5, -8}, <<22>>,
a -> {-9, -6, -7}, a -> {-4, 3, -9}, a -> {-5, -1, -6}, 
a -> {5, 7, -5}, a -> {-2, -3, 3}, a -> {1, 7, 3}, a -> {-7, -4, -4}} *)

(* if we need to keep the length of the list and replace entries where zero(s) exist *)

replacements = Range[-9, -1]~Join~Range[1, 9];
Replace[t, HoldPattern[a -> {OrderlessPatternSequence[(p : 0 ..),(t : Except[0] ..)]}] :>
a -> {t}~Join~ RandomChoice[replacements, Length@{p}], {1} ] // Short

(* {a -> {8, -2, -1}, a -> {6, 8, 2}, a -> {9, 5, -4}, a -> {9, -6, 3},
a -> {-7, 4, 8}, a -> {8, -5, -6}, a -> {4, 7, 2}, a -> {2, 3, -5},
<<35>>, a -> {-5, -1, -6}, a -> {5, 7, -5}, a -> {-2, -3, 3}, 
a -> {-4, 4, 5}, a -> {1, 7, 3}, a -> {-1, 9, -8}, a -> {-7, -4, -4}} *)
```

Comment: How to remove repeated elements, thanks for help

Comment: @jose sorry i am not able to understand. The code i posted in my solution either removes zeros or replaces them if found. What do you mean by repeated elements ??

Comment: @jose if what you mean is removing identical entries then you would need to apply `DeleteDuplicates` on the above results

Answer (score 0):

```
randomSigns[] := RandomChoice[{1, -1}, {3}]
randomNumber[n_] := RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {n, 3}]
a -> randomSigns[] # & /@ randomNumber[50]
```